# can’t run kdenlive

Tags: linux, arch-linux, software-installation, kdenlive

I get this error

> kdenlive: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.60:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Could you please provide more details? What OS are you using? Is the package installed? Etc. What does `/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep -i kdenlive` give you?

Comment: manjaro and that command returns nothing

Comment: What is the path of `libicui18n.so.60`?

Comment: i dont know any way to find it?

Comment: `find / -name "*libicui18n.so.60*"` should help you find it

Comment: i just used the GUIs search feature its /home/gus/pkg/tmp/usr/lib/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74854/discussion-between-jaken551-and-gus).